# Numero mayor a 5 en arraylist java

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de clase de unos alumnos los cuales los datos están dentro de un arraylist. El ejercicio manda que si los alumnos tienen una nota igual o superior a 5 se debe guardar en un fichero llamado aprobados y si tienen menos de 5 a suspensos. He intentado hacer un método recorriendo el arraylist y ver con un if si esa nota es igual o mayor a cinco pero me da error como ilegal start expresion.

Os dejo el código a ver si podéis echarme una mano:

```
public void notas(File aprobados, File suspensos) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String nombre = null;
        int nota = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < clase.size(); i++) {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
            if (clase.get(i).getNota() =  > 5) {

                if (!aprobados.exists()) {
                    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(aprobados, true));
                } else {
                    //hace lo mismo que la anterior pero omite la cabecera
                    oos = new MiObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(aprobados, true));
                }
                Alumno aprobado = new Alumno(nombre, nota);

                oos.writeObject(aprobado);
                oos.close();

            } else {
                if (!aprobados.exists()) {
                    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(suspensos, true));
                } else {
                    //hace lo mismo que la anterior pero omite la cabecera
                    oos = new MiObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(suspensos, true));
                }
                Alumno suspenso = new Alumno(nombre, nota);

                oos.writeObject(suspenso);
                oos.close();

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: =  > esta asi separado o todo junto? y en realidad no es este >= el que buscas?

Comment: separado o junto da el mismo fallo

Comment: claro.. porque no es ese.. edite mi comentario justo porque saliio antes de tiempo...

Comment: acabo de leer, tienes razón era eso, muchas gracias tio!

Comment: Esta pregunta se considera como error de tipeo. Este tipo de preguntas se suelen cerrar

Answer (score 1):

El operador de comparacion es incorrecto:

```
if (clase.get(i).getNota() =  > 5) {
```

Deberia ser:

```
if (clase.get(i).getNota() >= 5) {
```

En el siguiente enlace tienes los operadores de compracion de java.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html